# Load JSON file from local PC in Nativescript

Tags: javascript, json, nativescript

So I am having trouble displaying the contents of my JSON file in nativescript using console commands.I basically want to display these contents and use the values in the file to do some additional functions.

This is the JS function that I have slightly rewritten from the NS documentation and Emil Oberg's solution on a different post

```
    var fs = require('file-system');
    var documents = fs.knownFolders.documents();
    var jsonFile = documents.getFile('/Users/student/Desktop/Native_Script/Library/app/images/status.json');
    var array;
    var jsonData;


    //console.log('Item:' +jsonFile);

    jsonFile.readText()
    .then(function (content)
     {
        try {
        jsonData = JSON.parse(content);
        //console.log('Item:' + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
        array = new observableArrayModule.ObservableArray(jsonData);
    }   
    catch (err) {
       console.log(err);
}
console.log('Item:' +JSON.stringify(jsonData));

    });
```

////////////////

```
JSON File:
[{
    "Status": "3",
    "Trend": "increase",
    "Space": "Gleason"
}, {
    "Status": "2",
    "Trend": "decrease",
    "Space": "PRR"
}, {
    "Status": "4",
    "Trend": "stable",
    "Space": "WBR"
}, {
    "Status": "1",
    "Trend": "decrease",
    "Space": "HCR"
}]
```

So can someone tell where I am going wrong and how would I go about displaying any of the components of the file in the console. I essentially want to use one of the values in the file, say status, to call on another function.

So something like: (psuedocode)

status.getvalue 
.then(function) 
if status > 3 
console.log (place is crowded)

Comment: exactly HOW is this not working?

Comment: You spelled "cotnent" wrong: `console.log('Item:' + JSON.stringify(cotnent))`.

Comment: Whoops, I fixed that, but even still I get nothing in my console. I dont understand why console.log doesnt seem to be working for this file.

Comment: What error are you getting>

Comment: I am getting no error, thats the problem. I am not getting any sort of output from this file.

Comment: I am now getting this output:  CONSOLE LOG file:///app/second-page.js:48:20: Item:""
And this is when i put the console.log statement right after the opening bracket of the try method.

Comment: Shouldn't you be stringifying `jsonData`?

Comment: I tried jsonData too and yet I still get nothing.

Comment: You don't actually have any error handling. You're just throwing new errors. Try actually logging the errors you get.

Comment: So i added catch (err) { console.log(e);} the console sends me an error saying Unexpected EOF. I think it must be a parsing error, but I dont understand how I am parsing incorrectly.

Comment: I think I reduced the problem to it being a parsing error. Is my JSON parsing not correct or is there some other way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so here you're trying to read a file on your computer, from a device (iPhone/Android/Emulator/etc). This is simply not doable. The `getFile` call expects a path **on the device**.

So, either:

1. Store the JSON file on the device, or
2. Just `require()` the JSON file. E.g. `var jsonFile = require('status.json')` and it'll get read and parsed for you.

Comment: I put that in there and I still get an error that says  SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected EOF

Comment: So i removed the lines 
var documents = fs.knownFolders.documents();
var jsonFile = documents.getFile('status.json');
But then I cant execture the readText function. Any advice?

Comment: Just do `var jsonFile = require('status.json'); console.log(jsonFile)`

Comment: I have and it doesnt work, I am using the same exact code as above with info you gave me and the output I get is [object Object], and I have also used console.log('Item:' ,jsonFile) and other iterations, but the json does not populate in the console

Comment: Ok cool. I got that finally working. I dont understand why it just started working. But everytime I call jsonData i keep getting parser error. Can someone please explain to me why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Add something like below code, might be your jsonFile.readText() is throwing error

```
p1.then(function(value) {
  console.log(value); // "Success!"
  throw 'oh, no!';
}).catch(function(e) {
  console.log(e); // "oh, no!"
})

jsonFile.readText()
    .then(function (content)
      {
        try {
        jsonData = JSON.parse(content);
        //console.log('Item:' + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
        array = new observableArrayModule.ObservableArray(jsonData);
       }   
       catch (err) {
       console.log(err);
       }
       console.log('Item:' +JSON.stringify(jsonData));    
   })
  .catch(function(e) {
      console.log(e); // "oh, no!"
    });
```

Comment: I get two errors now: 
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/second-page.js:57:19: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected EOF
Jul 13 16:03:39 IDTStudentMBP Library[45129]: CONSOLE LOG file:///app/second-page.js:59:19: Item:undefined
Also added the throw "oh no" and it outputs oh no